# Css : move the information frame below the graph

Tags: jquery, css

I have this graph :

[image]

I framed the information in red.

And I would like a graph like this, just for the information frame:

[enter link description here](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqueryui-visualize/)

You can see the information is below the graph.

Here is the css :

```
/*plugin styles*/
.visualize { border: 1px solid #888; position: relative; background: #fafafa; margin-left :100px}
.visualize canvas { position: absolute;}
.visualize ul,.visualize li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

/*table title, key elements*/
.visualize .visualize-info { padding: -30px 5px; background: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #888; position: absolute; opacity: .6; margin-left:10px }
.visualize .visualize-title { display: block; color: #333; margin-bottom: 3px;  font-size: 1.1em; }
.visualize ul.visualize-key { list-style: none;  }
.visualize ul.visualize-key li { list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; position: relative;}
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-color { width: 6px; height: 6px; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -3px;  }
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-label { color: #000; }

/*pie labels*/
.visualize-pie .visualize-labels { list-style: none; }
.visualize-pie .visualize-label-pos, .visualize-pie .visualize-label { position: absolute;  margin: 0; padding:0; }
.visualize-pie .visualize-label { display: block; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1em; }
.visualize-pie-outside .visualize-label { color: #000; font-weight: normal; }

/*line,bar, area labels*/
.visualize-labels-x,.visualize-labels-y { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; list-style: none; }
.visualize-labels-x li, .visualize-labels-y li { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.label, .visualize-labels-y li span.label { position: absolute; color: #555; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line, .visualize-labels-y li span.line {  position: absolute; border: 0 solid #ccc; }
.visualize-labels-x li { height: 100%; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.label { top: 100%; margin-top: 5px; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line { border-left-width: 1px; height: 100%; display: block; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line { border: 0;} /*hide vertical lines on area, line, bar*/
.visualize-labels-y li { width: 100%;  }
.visualize-labels-y li span.label { right: 100%; margin-right: 5px; display: block; width: 100px; text-align: right; }
.visualize-labels-y li span.line { border-top-width: 1px; width: 100%; }
.visualize-bar .visualize-labels-x li span.label { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
```

Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title></title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jquery.visualize.plugin.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_statistic_3" class="display">
    <caption style="font-size: 20px">Test</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In my JavaScript, I did this

```
$('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });
```

atfer filling the DataTables that I load in the table.

Here is html code generated (part of info) :

```
<div class="visualize-info">
    <div class="visualize-title">Omzetcijfer per productgroep</div>
       <ul class="visualize-key">
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #be1e2d"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">Urology</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #666699"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">Procto</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #92d5ea"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">Pneumo</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #ee8310"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">Overigen</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #8d10ee"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">niet van toepassing</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #5a3b16"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label">Gastro</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #26a4ed"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label"> Nog niet bepaald</span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span class="visualize-key-color" style="background: #f45a90"></span>
           <span class="visualize-key-label"></span>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your html being generated? how we understand that which css is using where.. ?

Comment: @Era I edited the post. There is also the javascript file of plugin here : [link]https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Visualize/tree/master/js

Comment: No @Jayce it would not work. We need the html being generated with your javascript or try creating the same in http://jsfiddle.net/. I hope m clear now.